# ASP.NET MVC3 - Anti-CSRF and Session timeout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, csrf

I am implementing Anti-Forgery framework as described here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2010/04/14/guarding-against-csrf-attacks-in-asp-net-mvc2.aspx

Plus, to minimize the coding effort, I did the token insertion part at client side handling *form.onsumit* and *ajaxsend* events. Everything works fine – until the session expires.

In my application, I display a popup when the user session gets timed out where the user can re-login and continue without refreshing the current page so that the work-in-progress will be safe. But this doesn't  go well with the Anti-CSRF logic. When the user tries to re-login after a timed-out session, this throws a CSRF exception as the cookie (`__RequestVerificationToken_Lw__`) is already expired and all the future POSTs will be invalid until next page refresh.

Is there any way to set the cookie end time to a future date rather than 'session'? I tried to edit *Response.Cookie* but that made the cookie invalid.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: You could use jQuery and $.cookie("RequestVerificationToken_Lw", 1, { expires : 10 }); which would expire the cookie in 1 day (Which you can customise to a different timespan)

Comment: Thanks @DarrenDavies for the reply. but these cookies are httponly and cannot access using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of user session out (when displaying a popup) is it possible for you to set the httpcookie with expiry in server side.

I have extracted some code from the microsofts antiforgery token implementation.

```
internal static string GetAntiForgeryTokenName(string appPath)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(appPath))
            {
                return "__RequestVerificationToken";
            }
            return "__RequestVerificationToken_" + Base64EncodeForCookieName(appPath);
        }

    private static string Base64EncodeForCookieName(string s)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
        string text = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        return text.Replace('+', '.').Replace('/', '-').Replace('=', '_');
    }
```

Below code which set the cookie in server side.

```
string antiForgeryTokenName = GetAntiForgeryTokenName(HttpContext.Request.ApplicationPath);
            HttpCookie httpCookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies[antiForgeryTokenName];

            HttpCookie httpCookie2 = new HttpCookie(antiForgeryTokenName, httpCookie.Value)
            {
                HttpOnly = true
                //// your domain Domain = , 
                //// path Path = , 
                //// set path Expires = 
            };

            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Set(httpCookie2);
```

Please note that I haven't tested this code, just give a try if you dont have any other options.